# How to exclude .resx files from ReSharper name refactoring?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resx

I refactored a variable named `name` to `Name` and ReSharper also changed the `name` attributes in the resx files to `Name`, which of course led to several errors.

How can I exclude .resx files from ReSharper name refactoring, or if you can't: why is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#exclude_items

1. Open the Code Inspection | Settings page of ReSharper options.
2. In the left part of the Skipped elements section, use Add File and Add Folder buttons to specify files or folders to be ignored by the code inspection.
3. In the right part of this section, use the Add button to specify masks (e.g. *.xml) that will exclude all matching files in the solution from code inspection.
4. Click Save to apply the modifications and let ReSharper choose where to save them, or save the modifications to a specific settings layer using the Save To drop-down list.

Comment: After doing this, I still found that Resharper was still scanning the ignored files, even after clearing cache and restarting Visual Studio. I think this is purely just for code inspection, it doesn't seem to affect refactor renames?